# Docker - Error response from daemon: client is newer than server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-api

After creating a new machine with Docker Machine, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

```
$ docker ps
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server(client API version 1.21, server API version: 1.19)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
docker-machine upgrade <your-machine>
```

will do the trick. This can happen - as it did for me - even if you're not using RCs and your machine was newly created. It would be due to an ISO cache issue. The error is commented in [this thread](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2147).

> If the docker client is 1.9.x and the server is running docker 1.8.x,
>   the error message is observed.

Comment: THANKS!! Seems to solve my issue , what is <your-machine>  ?

Comment: the name of your docker-machine, typically default or dev

Answer (score 34):

If someone happens to get this error, but is not using `docker-machine`, there is another way to resolve the issue by specifying an older API version in an environment variable on the client side:

```
export DOCKER_API_VERSION=<version>
```

for example:

```
export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.19
```

and retrying the `docker` command.

[Reference](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-mac-stopped-running-docker-related-commands/16153/4).

Comment: Confirmed that this works on "Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" as well

Comment: Wow, when I didn't think I could be more unimpressed with docker, inc... Why doesn't it do this by itself, by default?

Answer (score 13):

On ubuntu distrib it happens after an apt update, if docker run as a service.
The client is updated but the old version of the server is still running.

In this case just do a:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: It was as simple as this!

Comment: If in doubt, re-boot/start!

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade your docker client you will not be able to use old docker-machine VMs. Actually you can force an upgrade with `docker-machine upgrade vm-name`, but if you are working with other distros (except boot2docker) as docker host like coreos, atomic, rancheros it may fail.

I am using Carina to manage more than one docker client version.

just install with `$ curl -sL https://download.getcarina.com/dvm/latest/install.sh | sh`
 (linux and mac installation) and run `dvm ls` to list installed versions, `dvm install 1.9.0` to install versions and `dvm use 1.8.1` to change your client version.

Very easy and powerfull. =)

Atention, for your safety always take a look inside scripts downloaded from internet before running them.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this error is due to `docker-machine` "falling asleep". Here is the magic command solving it for me:

```
$ docker-machine restart default
```

Or replace `default` by the name of your machine. 
The result is:

```
$ docker-machine restart default
Restarting "default"...
Restarted machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
```

As suggested, you may need to:

```
$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://....."
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=".../.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

And so you finally run that command:

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

From now it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with 1.10.0-rc4, and it turned out that boot2docker wasn't updated properly when installing a newer Docker Toolbox. I had to remove boot2docker manually:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/boot2docker
```

You can also delete the rest of the toolbox:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker*
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Docker
```

And finally install Docker Toolbox of the desired version.

Please see official uninstall script for [on GitHub for OS X here.](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/12afe715407b57f1b2c0c9a68c20c8714e73890f/osx/uninstall.sh)