# Docker-compose up causing client is newer than server error

Tags: docker

I get the following error when using the `docker-compose up` command:

```
ERROR: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.21, server API version: 1.20)
```

`docker -v` results in:

```
Docker version 1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3
```

`docker-compose -v` results in:

```
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - /srv/dockervolume/elasticsearch/var/lib/elasticsearch/data:/var/lib/elasticsearch/data
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
logstash:
  image: logstash:latest
  command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
  volumes:
    - /srv/dockervolume/logstash/etc/logstash/conf.d:/etc/logstash/conf.d
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
kibana:
  build: kibana:latest
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

I installed docker-compose via the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

Comment: Does this belong on http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Docker has way more tag numbers here on StackExchange. It might have something to do with the .yml file? I don't know.

Comment: A *nix admin would be better suited to answer these questions. Not saying someone here can't, but this is a Dev Ops question moreso than a programming question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker - Error response from daemon: client is newer than server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015271/docker-error-response-from-daemon-client-is-newer-than-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Docker versions / remote API version matrix at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/. Essentially, Docker Compose 1.6.x only supports back to client version 1.21 (which is in Docker version 1.9.x). You'll need to upgrade to at least Docker 1.9 or downgrade Docker Compose to 1.5.2.