# docker: Error response from daemon: client is newer than server

Tags: docker

I am trying to use docker but getting following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.23)
```

I am not using docker-machine.
All the other answers on internet suggest to do a docker-machine upgrade, but I am not using docker-machine here.

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of docker itself?

Comment: OS is RHEL 7.2 on a VM.

Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker - Error response from daemon: client is newer than server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015271/docker-error-response-from-daemon-client-is-newer-than-server)

Comment: @techraf

This answer refers does not refer to docker-machine.
The link you posted solves problem on docker-machine.

This is for docker-engine.

Comment: @Akki As an author of one of the answers I do not agree. The root cause is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility which does not involve docker-machine is illustrated in [issue 2159](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/2159) on Azure:

> I was able to work around this issue by `DOCKER_API_VERSION` to match the server version and move ahead.

See [this comment](https://github.com/meltwater/docker-cleanup/issues/13#issuecomment-217522741https://github.com/meltwater/docker-cleanup/issues/13#issuecomment-217522741):

> As of Docker 1.10, there is now support for the `DOCKER_API_VERSION` environment variable that allows you to dictate which API version that the client should use.

As mentioned in [docker issue 21930](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21930):

> There are many times when the Docker version on a client can differ to that on a server.
>
> This is typically because that end users are faster to update their clients whereas hosted Docker services or servers in production are slower to upgrade.
>
> This issue can be much worse when attempting to RC test the new version of Docker as you need to switch Docker Client versions or set `DOCKER_API_VERSION`.
> The latter can have consequences e.g newer client features and flags failing against older engine versions.