# Google Cloud Shell, Upgrade Docker from 1.9.1, it's impossible?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, google-cloud-shell

I followed this guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/

but nothing, after all steps my `docker version` is this:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:39:14 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.21)
```

It is always to `version 1.9.1`.

How to do?

I need docker-compose working with docker-compose.yml file `VERSION 2`.

So I need `docker-engine` at least 1.10.x.

*How to do?*

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015271/error-response-from-daemon-client-is-newer-than-server).

Comment: This doesn't solve. It always is 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to *temporarily* upgrade via:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo service docker restart
```

### Updated 2017-01

Cloud Shell upgraded their software to make `docker-compose` work again.